How adding a digital signature in a workbook Marked As Final - Excel 2016
I'm trying to insert a signature in a received workbook requiring that. But it is Marked As Final. A MARKED AS FINAL banner appears on top of the sheet when the workbook is open. Pressing Edit Anyway allows editing. I mean, changing data on its sheets but when I try inserting a signature, everything goes normally until the end, when the workbook must be saved with signature included. Now, the previously mentioned banner appears again and presing Edit Anyway does not work as it did for the content editing. A message saying "Editing will remove the signature in this workbook. Do you want to continue?" appears, showing only two options: Yes and No.
I found a way to remove Mark as Final flag in Excel 2007 but I couldn't find something similar in 2016. If I save it As a different name it keeps the respective flag...
I cannot believe it is not possible, that's why I'm looking for help on the issue.
As a workaround I exported it as pdf, digitally signed it and sent. It has been accepted, but I would like to understand what is to be done to sign the original workbook. Or its copy if such a way helps.
Thanks in advance!
